# upload 1 GB file to unix sever using java

Tags: java, jsch

My requirement is to copy the file from local machine(Windows) to unix serevr. I have the code which was working fine with some Mbs data. i am using jsch lib to connect and to transfer.
But now i have to transfer the files of 1GB, 2Gb or may be 5GB.
When i am using the same approach.
Its getting failed. Its stucking at

channelsftpObj.put(from,to);

and then exception is "faliure". Nothing else coming in exception.

May i know the reason or how can i transfer these files?

```
private boolean executeCommand (String localDir, String remoteDir, String fileList, String actionFlg) {
            boolean boolError = false;
            String localPath, destinationPath;
            ChannelSftp channelSFTPObj = (ChannelSftp) channelObj;
            for (int i = 0; i < filelistArr.length; i++ ) {
                localPath = localDir + "/" + filelistArr[i];
                destinationPath = remoteDir + "/" + filelistArr[i];
                try {
                        if (actionFlg.toLowerCase() == "upload") {
                            channelSFTPObj.put (localPath, destinationPath);
                            System.out.println ("Uploaded " + filelistArr[i] + " to " + remoteDir);    

                        }

                }
                catch (SftpException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    boolError = true;
                } 
            }
            channelSFTPObj.exit();
            return boolError;
        }
```

localDir is my path of my local system, remoteDir is the server path.
Successfully connected to the server.

Comment: Please post more code. We have no context here.

Comment: which version of jsch are you using ?

Comment: Jsch isn't incapable of transferring gigabyte-sized files. There are lots of reasons why file transfers can fail, particularly for large files that take a lot of time.

Comment: find the code in edit

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace to get more info from exception?

Comment: After the call to `channelSFTPObj.put()` starts, how much time passes before you get the exception? Is the file partially written on the remote server? How much of the file is written?